# Comparator and consistent with equals: How? (best practice)

Tags: java, collections, equals

I know that in order to be compliant with the contracts of Java's `Collections` (and to avoid unexpected behavior) any supplied `Comparator` should be consistent with equals.

Suppose I have Persons like this:

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private int age;


  public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.surname = surname;
     this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public String getSurname() { return surname; }
  public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

The Comparator would be

```
class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Person p1, Person p2) {
    // throws NPE's
    return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
  }
}
```

Now I want some sorted collection (`TreeMap`, `SortedSet`, ... whatsoever), using a `Comparator` that only compares a `Person`s name.
This Comparator would violate the "consistent with equals" contract. However I don't want to override `equals(Object o)`  because in other parts of the program two persons with same name, surname and age can be different (as in real life).

I want that in the selected collection, the name uniquely identifies a Person, i.e. a `TreeSet<Person>` cannot have "John Doe" and "John Smith" (same name).

This works fine with the current implementations of the Java Collections, as far as I have tested them.

My question is: How do you do this "correctly", ideally without breaking any contract? If possible I would like to avoid third party libraries, and of course I don't want to implement the data structures on my own just to get rid of the contract.
My concern is that my code might break in future Java releases because it violates the contract.

Comment: a `Comparator` doesn't have to be consistent with equals. `It is generally the case, but <i>not</i> strictly required that
      <tt>(compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y))</tt>.  Generally speaking,
      any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate
      this fact.  The recommended language is "Note: this comparator
      imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals."`

Comment: If all data in your `Person` class isn't enough to clearly identify a person then your model might be insufficient. Eventually you'll run into situations where you have multiple `Person` instances that are meant to represent the _same_ person. Thus I'd suggest to add some unique identifier and use that in `equals()` as well as your comparator.

Comment: @Thomas "It indicates that the model might be insufficient" - thanks, I think that's a good point. (My real use case is quite different, but I think the point might still apply...)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that Sets ignore duplicates. If you say two `Person` are the same it sees them as as duplicate and drops one of them.

```
return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
```

So if you have two people called "John" as a first name they will appear only once in a TreeSet.

What you need is to compare the same fields you do in equals e.g.

```
int cmp = p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
if (cmp == 0)
    cmp = p1.getSurname().compareTo(p2.getSurname());
if (cmp == 0)
    cmp = Integer.compare(p1.getAge() - p2.getAge());
return cmp;
```

This way you will only consider two people who are equals == true to be duplicates.

A way to ensure people who have the same details (but are different) from being treated as a duplicate is to add a unique id, either a counter or a UUID.

Note: the contract doesn't have to be consistent, and for BigDecimal it is not entirely consistent, but in this case, I don't see a good reason you would want to treat John Smith and John Doe as the same person.

Comment: Note that according to OP he wants to use `Object.equals()`, i.e. the comparator could return 0 for different (i.e. non-equal) instances.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I _want_ that the Set would drop the other John. That's intended. (My actual use case would be more complex, it's about non overlapping time intervals). So you don't see any problem with the inconsistency with equals? Is it good or at lease acceptable practice?

Comment: @user2055010 Technically, you can break the contract, but it is rarely a good idea.  Which record do you want to keep for John because it's not guaranteed to either be the first or the last.  If you want to keep all the first names I would use a `Set<String>` of first names. Possibly a `Map<String, List<Person>>`

Comment: Btw, `cmp = Integer.compare(p1.getAge() - p2.getAge());` should probably either be `cmp = Integer.compare(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge());` or `cmp = p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();` - I feel a typo here :)

Comment: @Peter My use case is time intervals. I want to check the relation between time intervals, which can be earlier (-1), later (+1) or overlap ( 0). But overlapping intervals are not necessary equal. I plan to encapsulate the underlying structure (Set) so that every modification checks for "contains" before operation. I know there are related libraries from Google, however I prefer to stick with the standard libraries. In my case, I would explicitly like to "remove" a time interval by just removing some "overlapping" interval, with length 1 to avoid "compareTo equality" with two set entires.

Comment: @user2055010 I am assuming your actual requirement has nothing to do with the Person structure, that is just an example? I would still use a Set or Map where the key has the only data you want to compare in it, rather than be a sub-set of fields. This makes it clear what you expect to be compared and what exactly should happen when your other fields don't match.

Comment: @Peter Indeed, my use case is time intervals with have start and end time. Maybe having different Maps, depending on what I want to compare (e.g. with start time as key) could be the way to go. Currently "overlapping" equaling "compareTo() == 0" works great, but this slight inaccuracy might raise problems when new requirements arise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation, if you are using Java 8, is that you use the utility methods in `Comparator` rather than write your own.

For example:

```
SortedSet<Person> people = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
```

That leaves all the complexity of implementation to the built-in method. It also allows you to take advantage of the various available methods to define multiple sort criteria, dealing with nulls etc. Because these methods are part of the API you can be confident your code won't break in future releases.